# Is it possible to change the video player seek time in the Apple Developer app in macOS?

Tags: macos, video

The video player in Apple Developer app has control buttons that seeks forward / backward 15 seconds. I feel this is too long. How can I change this value?

[image]

Comment: Good question. I think that is a default timing for HTML video. Have you seen [this post on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/304880) and can you try any of the keyboard short cut suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that `cmd + opt + left/right` key in macOS Developer app video player. It doesn't work.